# Unmount and mount between components in React-router v4.2

Tags: react-router-v4

I'm using react-router v 4.2 and meet some problems. There are two components:

First one is:

```
class One extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('One mount');
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('One unmount');
  }
  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Second one is:

```
class Two extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('Two mount');
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('Two unmount');
  }
  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

When I turn the page from component One to Two. And return to One. I would get:

> One mount >
>   One unmount >
>   Two mount
>   ***> One mount >
>   Two unmount***

The One was mounted first then Two unmounted. It's strange! Then, I tried to change the react-router to v3.0.0 then the problem was gone! So I think it was the problem in v4.2

Comment: The codepen example: https://codepen.io/Chuckthwu/pen/JOoOVp?editors=1111

Comment: The codepen example in v2.0 (The correct example): https://codepen.io/Chuckthwu/pen/RjNxwv?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Thanks for [Ernie Yang](https://www.facebook.com/ernieyang09?fref=gc&dti=521085554595481) in front-end community of Facebook: [Link](https://www.facebook.com/groups/f2e.tw/?multi_permalinks=1450860498284644&notif_id=1509380730024521&notif_t=like)

It simply added Switch component into route like:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/Two" component={Two} />
  <Route path="/One" component={One} />
</Switch>
```

The codepen created by Ernie Yang:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jaEKve?editors=1111

Comment: Please not that this won't work in React 16 since `componentWillUnmount` can fire asynchronously. More info about this here:  https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11106.